# Same Excel formula returns different results in Visual Studio C#

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, excel-2013

I am translating an Excel formula in my C# application, but it returns different results in Visual Studio. This is the formula (I have hard coded the variables with values in both Excel and Visual Studio for debugging):

```
LSBT = (0.085 - (0.0023 * (28 * (((4400 - 3600) / 63) - 12.857))));
```

when using in Excel, it returns:

```
0.095213022
```

and in Visual Studio it returns:

```
0.14019079999999995
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Far out you're right!!!

Comment: yeah, one have to be specifically mention the datatype with floating point values. my variables were double and excel calculated it on decimal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is loss of precision.

In c#, when you write a numeric literal, the compiler assumes you want it represented as an `int`, and when you use those literals in a formula, loss of precision can result. When you multiple or divide by values that have lost precision, the end result can be WAYYY off.

To avoid the issue, declare all numeric literals as a floating point type. In this example I express them with the suffix `M` which makes them into `decimal` variables.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var a = (0.085 -( 0.0023*(28*(((4400 - 3600)/63)-12.857))));
        var b = (0.085M -( 0.0023M*(28M*(((4400M - 3600M)/63M)-12.857M))));

        Console.WriteLine(a);
        Console.WriteLine(b);

    }
}
```

Output:

```
0.1401908
0.0952130222222222222222222222
```

[Code on DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/bymcLj)

Comment: that's nice. great explanation. Thank you